DropdownButton with static list is giving an error
I am trying to add a dropdownbutton to my flutter app. The dropdown will have a static list of items.
This is the code I am trying to use:
DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: const Text('Please choose transaction status'),
                  value: _trxnStatus,
                  onChanged: (_value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _trxnStatus = _value;
                    });
                  },
                  items: <String>[
                    'Select Status',
                    'Prospect',
                    'Listed',
                    'Under Contract',
                    'On Hold',
                    'Closed',
                    'Archived'
                  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String _value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: _value,
                      child: Text(_value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),

When I run this code, I am getting this error (sorry but it won't let me copy the text):

Why am I getting this error?
Thanks for your help.

Have you tried first constructing your List then dumping it to make sure your value props are all distinct?

How did you defined _trxnStatus. What is its type and initial value?

From the given code, everything seems normal except for the _trxnStatus state variable.
The exception pretty much straightly says, you must need EXACTLY one DropdownMenuItem matching the value of _trxnStatus. Since you're using the list of all possible values and mapping it to DropdownMenuItem the only possible way to get to this crash-site, you're initializing _trxnStatus to a different value at the beginning.
Try defining the _trxnStatus as nullable, and leave it null at first.
String? _trxnStatus;

Or set the initial value to a value inside the list.
String? _trxnStatus = "Select Status";

Hope this helps.

Try below code hope it's help to you.
List declaration:
List<String> list = <String>[
  'Select Status',
  'Prospect',
  'Listed',
  'Under Contract',
  'On Hold',
  'Closed',
  'Archived'
];

variable declartion:
String dropdownValue = list.first;

Dropdown Widget UI:
DropdownButton<String>(
  hint: const Text('Please choose transaction status'),
  value: dropdownValue,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = value!;
      print('Selected Value = $dropdownValue');
    });
  },
  items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
),

Read more about DropdownButton
